# pandas merge by coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two pandas tables where I find all rows in df2 which have coordinates close to each row in df1. Example follows.

```
df1: 
   x  y val
0  0  1   A
1  1  3   B
2  2  9   C

df2:
    x    y  val
0  1.2  2.8   a
1  0.9  3.1   b
2  2.0  9.5   c

desired result:
   x  y val_x val_y
0  0  1     A   NaN
1  1  3     B     a
2  1  3     B     b
3  2  0     C     c
```

Each row in df1 can have 0, 1, or many corresponding entries in df2, and finding the match should be done with a cartesian distance:

```
(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 < 1
```

The input dataframes have different sizes, even though they don't in this example. I can get close by iterating over the rows in df1  and finding the close values in df2, but am not sure what to do from there:

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    df2_subset = df2.loc[(df2.x - row.x)**2 + (df2.y - row.y)**2 < 1.0]
    # ?? What now?
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. I made this example with an ipython notebook, so which you can view/access here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/49a3d821420c04169f02

Comment: SQL is amenable to this but you'd have to convert the dataframes to tables first.  Syntax is pretty clean that way, but I'm not sure if it would be faster or not or how it would scale relative to what you already did.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer, though I am not real happy with having to loop over the rows in df1. In this case there are only a few hundred so I can deal with it, but it won't scale as well as something else. Solution:

```
df2_list = []
df1['merge_row'] = df1.index.values  # Make a row to merge on with the index values
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    df2_subset = df2.loc[(df2.x - row.x)**2 + (df2.y - row.y)**2 < 1.0]
    df2_subset['merge_row'] = i # Add a merge row
    df2_list.append(df2_subset)
df2_found = pd.concat(df2_list)

result = pd.merge(df1, df2_found, on='merge_row', how='left')
```